# C++: Copy constructor doesn't work when calling without lvalue

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor

When running test on a class I created I encountered something odd.

When I call the class's regular constructor:

```
MyClass::MyClass(const Type1& arg1, const Type2& arg2);
```

in the following manner:

```
MyClass(arg1, arg2);
```

It works perfectly.

But when I call the copy constructor:

```
MyClass::MyClass(const MyClass& other);
```

In the same manner:

```
MyClass(myClassInstance);
```

Then the compiler says: "redeclaration of 'MyClass myClassInstance'";

Comment: You want to create temporary ? use `{}` syntax to avoid unexpected parsing.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] as code fragments are no help in diagnosing this problem.

Comment: Did you mean `MyClass variable_name(myClassInstance);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MyClass(myClassInstance);
```

You are not calling copy constructor here what the compiler assumed is you meant,

```
int a;
int (a);
```

What you want is

```
MyClass anotherInstance(myClassInstance);
```

or

```
MyClass {myClassInstance};
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is, create an instance of **MyClass** and pass that object as a parameter for creating new instance(using copy constructor).

```
MyClass obj_1(arg1, arg2);
MyClass obj_2(obj_1);
```